# Travis-CI and Android JUnit Tests

Tags: android, junit, travis-ci

I am having a difficult time getting Travis-CI to run my unit tests. The following is my travis.yml code. Let me know if you need more information!

```
language: android
jdk: oraclejdk8
sudo: false

android:
  components:
    - platform-tools
    - tools
    - build-tools-24.0.2
    - android-22
    - android-24
    - sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-22
    - extra-android-m2repository

before_script:
  # Create and start emulator
  - echo no | android create avd --force -n test -t android-22 --abi armeabi-v7a
  - emulator -avd test -no-skin -no-audio -no-window &
  - android-wait-for-emulator
  - adb shell input keyevent 82 &

script:
    - ./gradlew connectedAndroidTest
```

Comment: What trouble are you having? What happens when your script runs on Travis CI?

Comment: My issue is that my unittests never get run. I purposefully made it so my unittests were incorrect, however my travis-CI build still passes!

Comment: Do you have unit tests in a `app/tests` subdirectory or instrumented tests in `app/androidTests`?

Comment: They are in app/tests

Comment: connectedAndroidTest runs instrumented tests in app/androidTests. See answer below for suggested fix.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I need more information to understand your specific issue. I'll update my answer if you do it.

The best would be that you share a link to a public travis-ci build, a log or a complert explanation.

Your `travis.yml` seems correct, perhaps you are trying to run unit tests not instrumentation tests:

```
script:
    - ./gradlew test
```

I also would add an extra tools option because the Travis-ci VMs are so outdated and you need to run a chain between tools and platform-tools to get the latest versions due to dependencies:

```
android:
  components:
    - tools
    - platform-tools
    - tools
```

Verify your [Espresso configuration](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/setup) if you re trying to run Android Tests and check [this guide](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/start/index.html).